# Query users with no activity for 3 days

Tags: mysql

I have a system in which users can send each other comments. I want to find users who haven't sent any comments for 3 days. Also, this will run on a daily cron and I only want them to receive an email once for every 3 days after their last comment, so I'm trying to look for their latest comment between 3 and 4 days.

Here's what I have:

```
$sql = "SELECT u.firstName, u.email 
        FROM user AS u
        LEFT JOIN comment AS c ON u.id=c.sender
        WHERE (DATE(c.date) BETWEEN ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 4 DAY ) 
              AND ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY )) 
              AND u.disabled=0 
        GROUP BY u.id";
```

Comment: Sorry but this sounds *horrible*. I'd hate to be getting emails saying 'you've been inactive for 3 days'. In fact I think it would be quite annoying being that tied to a system.

Comment: @jbutler483 please pass that message on to facebook

Comment: that's why I have multiple email accounts. that, or unsubscribe from all. @bwegs

Comment: Yeah I hate getting spammed with email as well, but this one's not up to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DATE_SUB which subtracts the interval from from the provided date

try this

```
$sql = "SELECT u.firstName, u.email 
        FROM user AS u
        LEFT JOIN comment AS c ON u.id=c.sender
        WHERE (DATE(c.date) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 4 DAY)
                 AND DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 3 DAY)
               AND u.disabled=0 
        GROUP BY u.id"
```

Comment: This is the one, thanks. My query was pulling everyone